# Lie bracket are equal when vector fields agree on neighbourhood of point.

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras

We have that $M$ is a manifold, $f \in C^\infty(M)$ and $X,Y$ and $Z$ are smooth vector fields on $M$. We also know that $Y$ and $Z$ agree in a neighbourhood $p \in M$. I now have to show that $[X,Y]|_p = [X,Z]|_p$.

I have tried the following: for every $f \in C^\infty(M)$ we know that 
$[fX,Y] = f[X,Y] - Y(f)X$. Is it true that I may assume that $Y(f)X = Z(f)X$ when I evaluate in $p$? Because then, we know that

$f[X,Y]|_p - f[X,Z]|_p = [X,Y]|_p - [X,Z]|_p$ for all $f$ and hence $[X,Y]|_p = [X,Z]|_p$.

Comment: As is often the case, it might be easier to consider $[X,(Y-Z)]$. What do you know about the vector field $Y-Z$?

Comment: We know that $Y-Z$ vanishes is the zero vector in the neighbourhood of $p$, although I probably should have mentioned that we need to use the identity of $[fX,Y]$ to solve this exercise

Comment: So a usual trick here is to introduce a bump function $\phi$ that is $1$ on a neighborhood of $p$, but supported inside the neighborhood on which $Y-Z=0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I have introduced such a bump function and we can now conclude that $[X, Y-Z]|_p = [X, \phi(Y-Z)]|_p $ but now I'm stuck again. Can you please give me another hint because I really have no clue what to do next

Comment: Further hints: Note that $\phi(Y-Z)$ is the zero vector field. And what do you know about $[X,\phi W]$?

Answer (score 1):

If $Y$ and $Z$ agree on a neighborhood of $p$, then on such neighborhood we have $Y(f) = Z(f)$ for all $f \in \mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$. Thus $X_p(Y(f)) = X_p(Z(f))$. Moreover, we have that $Y_p(X(f)) = Z_p(X(f))$, since in particular $Y_p=Z_p$. With this, we compute $$[X,Y]_p(f) = X_p(Y(f)) - Y_p(X(f)) = X_p(Z(f)) - Z_p(X(f)) = [X,Z]_p(f).$$

Comment: Is that true if $Y_{\gamma}=Z|_{\gamma}$ just along a small curve $\gamma$?